# Why is $\mathbb{R}^3 - A \simeq S^1 \vee S^2$? Where $A$ is a circle.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology

I'm looking at page 46 of Hatcher's text on Algebraic topology and do not understand why removing a circle from $\mathbb{R}^3$ yields $S^1 \vee S^2$. I don't understand why there are two linked circles within a sphere a why this is $\mathbb{R}^3 - A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the open cube to avoid getting lost in the largeness of $3$-space. Draw a solid torus inside it, and now push it outwards while creating a pillar in the middle. Now collapse this pillar to a segment. You get a $2$-sphere (the boundary of the cube) plus a diameter, and this is homotopy equivalent to $S^2\vee S^1$.

Comment: Thanks, may I ask why Hatcher has a link around the segment? He claims this to be $S^1 \vee S^2$.

Comment: @Jordan What do you mean by a link? You can pass the diameter inside $S^2$ to be outside, and then collapse a path from the endpoints to form an $S^1$ joined at a point to $S^2$ (the diameter is not trapped inside $S^2$!)

Answer (score 4):

It may help your intuition that $\mathbb{R}^3$ deformation-retracts onto the closed ball $B$ of radius $2$. Now remove the circle $A = \{(x,y,z)\ |\ x^2 + y^2=1, z=0\}$ from $B$. Notice that the space $B-A$ is homotopy equivalent to a ball with a donut removed, which is homotopy equivalent to its boundary sphere with a line segment connecting the north and south poles. (Visualize this as "inflating" the removed set $A$.)

Do you see why the result is homotopy equivalent to $S^1\vee S^2$?

Comment: Heh, we think alike.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Great minds ... !